# Where could I host premium large files for my android app?

Tags: android, google-play, hosting, shared-hosting

Where could I store large files (200 MB to 2 GB, a **total of less than 6-10 GB**) that will be downloaded after the user purchases them? My primary concerns are:

1. Download Speed
2. Reliability (always available)
3. Resume capability
4. **FREE** (I can't afford to pay anything to be honest)

BTW, security is not an issue at all. I'm willing to expose the files in the web as long as the three above are satisfied.

My research says that I have few alternatives:

- Use expansion files (the problem is Google only allows two 2 GB expansion files and I'm selling more than that both in numbers and in size)
- File hosting services (This is really my main question. Are the likes of **Dropbox, Google Drive, FileDropper, etc.** feasible according to the conditions I mentioned above?

And lastly, just to confirm as my research says that it doesn't (i'm not sure though), does Google Play allow such hosting of premium files to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually based on the 4th Point that you made i would suggest these:

**Dropbox**

Dropbox basic plan offers 2GB storage which is not enough for you as you have mention 6-10GB for you files.

**Microsoft OneDrive**

Microsoft OneDrive offers 5GB for the free account and it also offers basic account with 2$/month(everyone can afford this i guess) for 50GB storage.

**Google Drive**

Google Drive offers you 15GB for free which covers your storage limits, its trustfull, offers limited access with privileges(only certain email adresses can have access to the files if you want) which will be security for your files and not just expose them to the public for free. It also offers 100GB with 2$/month.

**Mega**

Mega is considered by me the best option available since it provides you with 50GB storage in a absolutely free account with RSA - 2048 bit encryption. You still can limit access to your files so that not just anyone can see them and is always reliable. I use it for 5 years now for file transfers and absolutely no problemm.

There are also other cloud storage if you weren't satisfied with the above like **Box**, **pCloud**, **Tresorit**, **Mediafire**, **Amazon Cloud**, **Spiderroak**, **Mozy**

Hope it helps!!!!

Comment: But my question is that do these services not restrict the bandwidth or download speed of the files when there are too many people downloading them. In other words, are there no daily limits? Thank you.

Comment: there are no daily limits. no restrictions to the bandwidth and many users can download files simultaneously

Comment: The encryption information about Mega is incorrect. The data is AES CTR encrypted with a 128-bit key. In addition each user account has a 2048-bit RSA key pair to securely receive keys. Note, RSA is not an encryption method for data, it is very slow and can not encrypt data larger than the key size, in the case of a 2048-bit ken the maximum data size is 245-bytes.